# ADMA5014E error installing Mavenized Java application to WebSphere with NoModuleFileException: "A file does not exist for module element having uri"

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere

after mavenizing an existing java application , while running the project I get the below error. I don't get any error, while building the `Maven` project, but only `right click -> run as server` I get the below error

```js
======== AppEAR========

Failed to add or remove the application from the server: appEAR
[3/15/19 11:49:50:857 IST] 00000076 InstallSchedu I   ADMA5016I: Installation of appEAR started.
[3/15/19 11:49:52:572 IST] 00000076 wtp           W org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.LoadStrategyImpl collectFilesFromLooseArchives Archive URI [ C:\UBS\Dev\Maven\ws45\appEAR ]: Loose archive URI [ app-1.0.war ] Loose Archive [ org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.looseconfig.internal.impl.LooseLibraryImpl@870e53f6 (uri: app-1.0.war, binariesPath: C:/UBS/Dev/Maven/ws45/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0\app, resourcesPath: C:/UBS/Dev/Maven/ws45/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0\app, archiveType: <unset>, otherArchiveType: null, archiveVersion: <unset>) ]: Already mapped to [ com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.WARFileImpl@9278d82b (URI: app-1.0.war, lastModified: 0, size: 0, directoryEntry: <unset>, originalURI: app-1.0.war) (types: null) ]
[3/15/19 11:49:58:378 IST] 00000076 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Programs\IBM\WebSphere855\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_618314b7_19.03.15_11.49.58.2754582458384981183218.txt com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ConfigureTask.performTask 471
[3/15/19 11:49:58:570 IST] 00000076 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Programs\IBM\WebSphere855\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_618314b7_19.03.15_11.49.58.5108999045291617931632.txt com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ConfigureTask.performTask 484
[3/15/19 11:49:58:618 IST] 00000076 InstallSchedu I   ADMA5014E: The installation of application appEAR failed.
[3/15/19 11:49:58:571 IST] 00000076 SystemErr     R org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.ArchiveWrappedException
Stack trace of nested exception:
org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.NoModuleFileException: A file does not exist for module element having uri: app.war
 at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.ModuleRefImpl.checkType(ModuleRefImpl.java:591)
 at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.ModuleRefImpl.initModuleFileFromEAR(ModuleRefImpl.java:167)
 at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.ModuleRefImpl.getModuleFile(ModuleRefImpl.java:120)
 at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.EARFileImpl.getModuleFile(EARFileImpl.java:166)
 at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.EARFileImpl.getDeploymentDescriptor(EARFileImpl.java:842)
 at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.ModuleRefImpl.getDeploymentDescriptor(ModuleRefImpl.java:230)
 at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.ModuleRefImpl.getDeploymentDescriptor(ModuleRefImpl.java:223)
 at com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ConfigureTask.createWebModuleDeployment(ConfigureTask.java:2106)
 at com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ConfigureTask.createMD(ConfigureTask.java:2008)
 at com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ConfigureTask.createMDsForModuleRefs(ConfigureTask.java:1217)
 at com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ConfigureTask.createMDsIfNeeded(ConfigureTask.java:1085)
 at com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ConfigureTask.reconcileModuleDeployment(ConfigureTask.java:984)
 at com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ConfigureTask.performTask(ConfigureTask.java:370)
 at com.ibm.ws.management.application.SchedulerImpl.run(SchedulerImpl.java:315)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:790)

[3/15/19 11:49:58:571 IST] 00000076 SystemErr     R Stack trace of nested exception:
[3/15/19 11:49:58:572 IST] 00000076 SystemErr     R org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.NoModuleFileException: A file does not exist for module element having uri: app.war
[3/15/19 11:49:58:572 IST] 00000076 SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.ModuleRefImpl.checkType(ModuleRefImpl.java:591)
[3/15/19 11:49:58:579 IST] 00000076 SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.ModuleRefImpl.initModuleFileFromEAR(ModuleRefImpl.java:167)
[3/15/19 11:49:58:579 IST] 00000076 SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.ModuleRefImpl.getModuleFile(ModuleRefImpl.java:120)
[3/15/19 11:49:58:580 IST] 00000076 SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.EARFileImpl.getModuleFile(EARFileImpl.java:166)
[3/15/19 11:49:58:580 IST] 00000076 SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.EARFileImpl.getDeploymentDescriptor(EARFileImpl.java:842)
[3/15/19 11:49:58:587 IST] 00000076 SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.ModuleRefImpl.getDeploymentDescriptor(ModuleRefImpl.java:230)
[3/15/19 11:49:58:587 IST] 00000076 SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.ModuleRefImpl.getDeploymentDescriptor(ModuleRefImpl.java:223)
[3/15/19 11:49:58:588 IST] 00000076 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ConfigureTask.createWebModuleDeployment(ConfigureTask.java:2106)
[3/15/19 11:49:58:588 IST] 00000076 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ConfigureTask.createMD(ConfigureTask.java:2008)
[3/15/19 11:49:58:588 IST] 00000076 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ConfigureTask.createMDsForModuleRefs(ConfigureTask.java:1217)
[3/15/19 11:49:58:588 IST] 00000076 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ConfigureTask.createMDsIfNeeded(ConfigureTask.java:1085)
[3/15/19 11:49:58:588 IST] 00000076 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ConfigureTask.reconcileModuleDeployment(ConfigureTask.java:984)
[3/15/19 11:49:58:588 IST] 00000076 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ConfigureTask.performTask(ConfigureTask.java:370)
[3/15/19 11:49:58:589 IST] 00000076 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.application.SchedulerImpl.run(SchedulerImpl.java:315)
[3/15/19 11:49:58:589 IST] 00000076 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:790)
```

Comment: Does `A file does not exist for module element having uri: gsp.war` mean anything to you? It is unlikely we can help as we do not know anything about your application's structure.

Comment: before mavenizing the project was working fine , but after mavenizing i get this weird error. I dont get what file its looking for i found this link , but its not saying anyting https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.install.doc/refs/rignofileuri.htm so checking in SO if anyone has encountered similar error

Comment: _checking in SO if anyone has encountered similar error_ -- That's not quite how this site works; StackOverflow is not a discussion forum.  Please visit the [help], take the [tour] and especially read [ask].

Comment: Alright Jim - Thanks for showing your "Tough Love"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok .. Here is the solution. This may help "if anyone has encountered similar error" :)

my project has two folders

1. app -> creates WAR file
2. appEAR -> creates EAR file(this `ear` file acts like a wrapper for the above `war` file)

the `application.xml` (path is `appEAR -> META-INF -> application.xml`)

change the value inside the tag `web-uri` from this 
`app.war` to 
      `app-1.0.war` because the name of war file created is `app-1.0.war` not `app.war`

update the project and run again. It works.

*it's simple , once you know the solution*